# Notification observer calling only when pressing the text fields that I want in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I have a notification observer that get called when the keyboard appears.
In my storyboard I have 2 text fields, and I'm only interested in calling to the keyboardWillShow function only when pressing one of that 2 text fields. Is there a way to tell the app to only work when pressing one of the 2 text fields using NSNotificationCenter?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {    
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
} 

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
    let keyboardFrame:NSValue = userInfo.valueForKey(UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey) as! NSValue
    let keyboardRectangle = keyboardFrame.CGRectValue()

    if keyboardRectangle.height > 216 {
        keyboardHeight = keyboardRectangle.height
        keyBoardAppeared()
    }
}

func keyBoardAppeared() {
    self.addAvatarView.center.y = (self.globalView.frame.size.height - keyboardHeight) / 2
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

So make yourself a delegate of the two TextFields in `viewDidLoad`

```
textField1.delegate = self
textField2.delegate = self
```

(this requires that you implement UITextFieldDelegate)

And then whenever one gets clicked/wants to edit, store which one it is in an overrided `textFieldShouldBeginEditing`, and nil it in `textFieldDidEndEditing.`  Then you'll know in your `keyboardWillShow` which (if any) TextField triggered the keyboard